# what's the difference between Browsers and Node?

Tags: javascript, browser, node.js

what's the difference between Browsers and Node? for instance:

`setName.js` on Node:

```
var setName;
setName = function (name) {
    return this.name = name;
};
setName("LuLu");
//LuLu
console.log(name);
//undefined
console.log(this.name);
```

`setName.html` in browser:

```
<script>
    var setName;
    setName = function (name) {
        return this.name = name;
    };
    setName("LuLu");
    //LuLu
    console.log(name);
    //LuLu
    console.log(this.name);
</script>
```

the the second log is different,why?

Comment: it is really "undefined",my node version is `v0.4.10`

Comment: (1) We try to avoid global variables in the browser. (2) You want to start writing strict-mode code, in which case the above code throws...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Node is a JavaScript engine, not a browser. The specific reason that you see `undefined` in Node, and `Lulu` in a browser? [Differences in the global namespace](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html):

> In browsers, the top-level scope is the global scope. That means that in browsers if you're in the global scope `var something` will define a global variable. In Node this is different. The top-level scope is not the global scope; `var something` inside a Node module will be local to that module.

In the browser, `this` is a reference to the `window` object — the browser's global namespace — for all functions which are invoked unattached to an object (e.g. *not* like `foo.bar()`). In Node, `this` is simply not a reference to the global namespace.

---

**N.B.** `console.log(this.name)` in a Node interpreter will print `Lulu`, not `undefined`. That's because, **in the REPL only,**

```
> this === global
true
```

---

Further reading @ [How To Node: What is "this?"](http://howtonode.org/what-is-this)

---

Okay, one more edit as prompted by [@Šime Vidas'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/425275/ime-vidas) comment regarding [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in [ES5 strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode):

> - In the global context (outside of any function), `this` refers to the global object, whether in strict mode or not.
> - When the `this` keyword occurs inside a function, its value depends on [how the function is called](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context).
> - When a function is called as a method of an object, its `this` is set to the object the method is called on.

More interesting reading courtesy of [Juriy Zaytsev (aka @kangax)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130652/kangax) in [one of his blog posts](http://perfectionkills.com/2011/03/#ecmascript_5_strict_mode).

Comment: Consider making your answer more future-oriented by adding information about strict mode. (In function bodies, `this` is undefined unless explicitly set by the invocation method.)

Comment: i want to know why `console.log this.name` output `undefined`?

Comment: @island205 because, unless you're in the REPL, `this !== global`. Look at the differences between `console.log(this)` in a browser, the REPL, and a node script. I don't know the exact reasoning for these differences, but I do know that **NodeJS is not a browser.**

Comment: @island205 what do you mean by "the" difference? Are you asking "why is this different in Node and a browser?"

Comment: ` exact reasoning for these differences`.forgive my careless

Answer (score 2):

Your browser code has the `window` host object. Node does not have that host object. When you set `this.name`, you are actually setting it to the `window` object aka making a **global** variable.

`window.name === this.name // true`