# Why does JavaScript "this" returns different values in Node and Browser environments?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, binding, this

After watching Kyle Simpson's [Advanced JavaScript](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/advanced-javascript) course on Pluralsight, I created a simple code snippet to try out `this` binding. I usually work in SublimeText editor and have node build engine configured in it and occasionally I run the same code in browser as well. I have noticed one difference in the program output when execute code in Node and in Browser [Chrome].

Following is the code snippet to try out `this` binding.

```
function foo() {
    console.log(this.bar);
}

var bar = "bar1";
var obj = {bar : "bar2"};

foo();
foo.call(obj);
```

When I execute it using Sublime, it returns `undefined` and `bar2`. However when I execute same snippet in a browser it returns `bar1` and `bar2`, which I think is correct since variable `bar` is defined at global scope. I am not able to understand why Node environment is returning it as `undefined`. Kindly help.

Comment: This is why all Javascript code should be run in strict mode.  Then, wrong code won't accidentally work sometimes, but not other times. The invocation of `foo()` and the subsequent reference to `this.bar` inside of `foo()` is simply just bad code that accidentally works sometimes in a browser because you coincidentally have a global variable with the same name as the property you're trying to reference and `this` is set to `window` in a browser not running in strict mode and globals are properties of the `window` object.  Run in strict mode and this error will be immediately shown to you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meaning of "this" in node.js module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770299/meaning-of-this-in-node-js-module)

Comment: Basically, in the browser `this === window`, but in Node `this !== global` and var outside a closure in a Node module does not create a global variable anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jfriend00 for quick response and clarifying the doubt.

Comment: @PrasadHonrao - I expanded my comment into an answer which explains in detail what is happening in the node.js case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what's the difference between Browsers and Node?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8624913/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In node.js, your `bar` variable is a module variable which is local to that module.  It is not a global variable.  Globals in node must be explicitly assigned to the `global` object.  Top level declarations in a node.js module are not automatically globals like they are in a browser JS file.  Technically, they exist inside a function scope that is created by the module loader so they are local variables to the module's function scope.

In node.js, the value of `this` in a plain function call like `foo()` is the `global` object.

But, in node.js, your `bar` variable is NOT a property of the global object.  So, when you try to reference `this.bar`, that's `global.bar` and there is no property on the global object by that name.

So, in node.js, you're essentially doing this:

```
// create a function which is like the module scope
function myModuleFunc() {
    function foo() {
        // the value of this in a plain function call in node.js is the
        // global object
        console.log(global.bar);
    }

    // this isn't a global
    var bar = "bar1";

    foo();
}

// execute that module scope function
myModuleFunction();
```

And, hopefully you can see why there is no `global.bar` property, thus you get `undefined`.

---

This all accidentally works in a browser because `var bar` is a global and globals are on the `window` object and `this === window` so it accidentally works.  Two wrongs make a right that works only sometimes.

As I said in my comment, it is highly recommended to run your code in strict mode and things will not accidentally work sometimes, but not others - this issue will all be highly consistent and you will get an immediate error when you have written the wrong sort of code.

---

Though you said you already understand what is happening in the browser environment, since your question asks why the two are different, I will describe the browser situation just to cover all the bases.

In the browser, the value of `this` in a plain function call (when not in strict mode) is the `window` object.

In the browser, your `bar` variable is a global variable and thus automatically becomes a property of the `window` object.

So, in the browser, you are essentially doing this:

```
function foo() {
    console.log(window.bar);
}

window.bar = "bar1";

foo();
```

And, thus you can see why it happily creates a property on the `window` object and then references it.

Comment: This is absolutely the correct answer and is exactly how I would have answered it. :) In addition, I'd say that there are other cases where Node has inconsistency with browsers on `this` behavior, such as with `setTimeout(..)`. The browser standard says timers should always fire in global (regardless of strict mode), but in Node, they violate this and always fire timers in the context of a proprietary (node-only) timer object.

Comment: @jfriend00 I cant thank you enough for such a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

That is because of the variable declaration `var bar = "bar1";`, That is declared in the global scope. All global variables are available as properties of the window object.

When you call `foo()` without any context the default context of the method is the `window` object(in non strict mode), so your code execution becomes `console.log(window.bar);`, as we have seen above your `bar` variable has attached itself to the window object as a property, so its prints the value `bar1`

```js
function foo() {
  snippet.log('is window:' + (this instanceof Window))
  snippet.log('bar value: ' + this.bar);
}

var bar = "bar1";
snippet.log('window.bar: ' + window.bar)

var obj = {
  bar: "bar2"
};

foo();
foo.call(obj);
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am not confused about browser output, which as I mentioned seems to be correct. The Node environment returns it as `undefined` and I don't know why, and so the question.