# Can we use nodemailer without express and bodyParser

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I want to use nodemailer in plain javascript without express and body parser
can it be possible.

```
      <form action="POST">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name"/>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="" name="email"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Message" id="" name="message"/>
      <button type="submit" value="submit">Send</button>
      <form>
```

I want to send the mail using nodemailer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use nodemailer in browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37630543/can-i-use-nodemailer-in-browser)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to use nodemailer in the browser, outside of Node.js?

Comment: What do you mean in by browser? Actually, I am using nodemailer for portfolio contact form.
Now you have the idea

Comment: What do you mean by "plain javascript"? Is nodemailer running in Node.js? Or in Chrome/Firefox/...?

Comment: without express or anything like this using vanilla javascript

Comment: I understand that part (although express is vanilla Javascript itself). I rather ask for the context. Where do you want to execute nodemailer? :) Maybe [this stackoverflow question helps to understand the difference between a Browser and Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624913/whats-the-difference-between-browsers-and-node).